# Why are we able to take the union here?, also axiom of countable choice.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In theorem 8.3 in Munkres Topology, he takes the union over some functions, and the functions are regarded as collection of ordered pairs. But in order to do this, must we not first prove that $\{f_1,f_2,.\dots \}$ is a set? How is he sure that it is a set?

First he has sopme relevant lemmas:

[image]

Then he proves the theorem I am talking about:
[image]

But he has not proved that $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots\}$ is a set?

For instance if $\{A_n\}$ is a countable collection of nonempty set. For each n we know that there exists an ordered pair $(A_n,a_n), a_n \in A_n$ since $A_n$ is nonempty. But if we also have that $\{(A_1,a_1),(A_2,a_2),\ldots\}$ is a set, we have proved the axiom of countable choice?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it should follow from the axiom of replacement, by replacing $n$ with $f_n$. That $\mathbb N$ is a set follows from the axiom of infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f_n$ is *unique* (Munkres mentions this in his proof). So, we have a formula $\varphi$ assigning, to each natural number $n$, a unique set $f_n$. Then $\{f_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ exists by Replacement.

Were the $f_n$s *not* uniquely determined by $n$, then this would indeed need some amount of the axiom of choice (or a clever argument explaining how to pick out a specific $f_n$ for each $n$, without choice).

---

Actually, we would *never* need the axiom of choice here! Specifically, suppose for each $n$ we have a nonempty set of functions $F_n$. Then let $f_n$ be the *lexicographically least* element of $F_n$. This relies on two properties: that the *domain* be finite, and that the *range* be well-orderable.

- Note that a set of functions $G$ from an *infinite* set $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ need not have a lexicographically least element, even if $A$ is well-ordered; consider the set $$G=\{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}: \exists n(f(n)\not=0)\}.$$ The lexicographically least element of $G$ *would* be the constantly-zero map, but that's not an element of $G$!
- Note also that a set $G$ of functions from a singleton $\{a\}$ to a *non-well-orderable* set $B$ (such exist without the Axiom of Choice) need not have a lexicographically least element.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question, I hope it is ok. Could we have used the axiom of specification here. And consider the set: $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_+\times C: P((a,b))\}$. Where P is a predicate which is: $P((a,b))$="There exist a function $t:\{1,2,\ldots a\}\rightarrow C$ that satisfies *, and $t(a)=b$". Would this be a legal predicate and operation to create the desired union?

Comment: @user119615 Yes, that is correct.